# how to generate nested property path names from a java bean?

Tags: java, apache-commons-beanutils

Given a java bean def like below

```
public class MyBean {
private String name;
private String age;
private Address address;
}
```

I am looking for utility class that can generate all possible deep nested property path names from the above bean like

```
"name",
"age",
"address.streetAddress"
"address.city"
"address.state"
"address.zip.zip5"
"address.zip.zip4"
```

Currently apache bean utils package can generate properties given a bean but not for inner objects like address.
Is there any utility class from Spring? I am guessing that propjects like Spring Roo needs such a utility, if they have to auto generate Forms given a command object.
Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks
sri

Comment: Out of curiosity, what did you end up doing?